# .NET Regex issue, also .NET regex uses a different rule engine?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match text in a string around an equals sign.
My regex is this:  `"((?:\\S+\\s)?\\S*=)(\\S*(?:\\s\\S+)?)"` (the `\\` are there because C# doesn't like to use the '\' string unescaped).

Given the string `"the thing=12 and otherthing = 'thirty'"` this returns groups of:  "the thing=", "12 and", "otherthing =" and "'thirty'".

I am bad at Regex and I'm not sure what to do next.
I need this to return groups of: "thing", "12", "otherthing" and "thirty" (notice the stripped out single quotes in "thirty").

Can anyone help me with this?  It seems like the C# Regex parser is different than the one on gskinner.com as I thought I had some of this working but it doesn't in C#.

Comment: Try using the @ symbol in front of your string literal. e.g. @"my \S string"  If you do that you wont have to escape your backslashes.

Comment: Have you seen http://regexhero.net/ ? Just used it the other day to play around with a regex I was writing in .NET.

Comment: So what you really need is to split the string by `=` and space characters, and remove `'` characters?

Comment: FYI, you're not asking about the C# Regex engine. You're asking about the .NET Regex engine. C# has no Regex support in the language (unlike JavaScript, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern takes the first word (consecutive non-spaces) before the `=` and the following quoted value or first word.

`@"(?<name>[^ =]+?)\s*=\s*('(?<value>[^']+)'|(?<value>[^\s]+))"`

(In C#, it is often best to use a literal string `@"\s"` for regexs because you only need to escape double-quotes.  `@"\s""" == "\\s\""`)

```
var pattern = @"(?<name>[^ =]+?)\s*=\s*('(?<value>[^']+)'|(?<value>[^\s]+))";
var s = "the thing=12 and otherthing = 'thirty'";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(s, pattern))
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", 
      match.Groups["name"].Value,
      match.Groups["value"].Value);
```

For `the thing=12 and otherthing = 'thirty'`, it yields:

```
thing = 12
otherthing = thirty
```

Comment: Can I ask about some decisions you made?  Why do `[^ =]` and not `[^\s=]`?  Right after that you use both `+` and `?`.  As far as I can tell, the `?` is pointless there no?  I haven't gotten to the "value" side of it yet but I'm just trying to understand why you do it a certain way.

Comment: `?` causes matches to be minimal instead of maximal. Otherwise, matches are always maximal. So if there were multiple instances of `=` in your string (which there are), without the `?`, you'd match everything up to the last instance, including all other instances of `=` (you wouldn't match the last instance because it would still need to match the rest of the pattern somehow).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
string input = "bob = 20 joe=thirty";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<left>[^=]+?)\s+=\s+(?<right>[^\s]+)");
foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", 
        match.Groups["left"].Value,
        match.Groups["right"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx%20%22String.Split%22.). If you're certain you need regex, you can use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx).

Comment: That's probably true, but this is just a practice thing and I want to learn Regex.